# unknown intent intent

Tags: android, eclipse, nfc

This is the error that shows on my logcat when i run my TagViewer.java for NFC on Eclipse. I am running a NFC program and basically it runs however at a certain period of time the program shuts down on its own.

`08-29 14:06:33.677: E/ViewTag(22056): Unknown intent Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10000000 cmp=com.example.android.nfc/.TagViewer }`

This is from my Android Manifest. I am guessing that the error is from here because of the line on the error `android.intent.action.MAIN` and such.

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 package="com.example.android.nfc"
 android:versionCode="1"
 android:versionName="1.0" >

 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.NFC" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE"/>
 <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.nfc" android:required="true"/>

 <uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="9"
    android:targetSdkVersion="16" />

 <application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".TagViewer"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_main" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />                

            <intent-filter> 
              <action android:name="android.nfc.action.TAG_DISCOVERED"/>    
              <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            </intent-filter>

        </intent-filter>

    </activity>
 </application>
</manifest>
```

this is from my java and basically the last line, when i put // the program will not shut down but it will show like a white page.However the title NFC is still showing so i know that it is slightly working

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
       mTagContent = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.tag_viewer);
        mTitle = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.title);
      resolveIntent(getIntent());
    }
```

Comment: In the XML above you have an intent filter nested inside another intent filter. That is not correct.

Comment: @NFCguy so i should be getting rid of the second intent-filter right? same problem, i will get the same error on my logcat

Comment: The 2nd intent filter is declared *inside* the first one, that is not correct. It should be declared after (or before) the first one. However, I have no idea how this relates to the specific error you have. Perhaps showing more lines from logcat could give more insight.

Comment: @NFCguy sorry i'm really new at this.. actually i noticed that on the java

Answer (score 1):

Change your Declaration activity `"TagViewer"` instead of `".TagViewer"`

Comment: @user you should direct your comment at divyata. I justed edited the formatting in that user's post and don't really know anything about Android.